# Get tip changeset of remote Mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

My .hg/hgrc file has the line:

`default = http://some/remote/repository`

Is there a quick command to print the tip revision of that repository (which may or may not be inside my local repository)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [identify command](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#identify) like this:

```
$ hg identify $(hg paths default)
```

This is one of the few commands that can operate on a remote repository. If you need more information about the remote repository, then I suggest you take a look at `hg incoming`.

Comment: awesome - thanks! For anyone else using this, if you're just looking to get the id for the revision, use the flag `-i` (for scripting and such)

Answer (score 2):

The following returns the latest changeset number (tip) of a remote repository:

```
hg identify --id http://www.myrepo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

hg id default

This is a shorter form of "hg identify $(hg paths default)".